# May I create an instance of a structure using a simple Int?

Tags: swift, structure, instance

Is it right to make a structure's instance this way?

```
public struct Barometer {
   public var pressure: Int
   public init(pressure: Int) {
      self.pressure = pressure
   }
} 

var barometer: Barometer = 80
```

Or I need to adopt a protocol?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I mean "is it right"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make that work by adopting the `IntegerLiteralConvertible`
protocol:

```
extension Barometer: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.init(pressure: value)
    }
}
```

Now a `Barometer` value can be instantiated from a literal integer:

```
let barometer: Barometer = 80
print(barometer) // Barometer(pressure: 80)
```

But note that this works only with literals, not with arbitrary
integer values:

```
let p = 80
let barometer: Barometer = p
// error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to specified type 'Barometer'

// You have to use:
let barometer = Barometer(pressure: p)
```

For **Swift 3,** replace `IntegerLiteralConvertible` by
`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`.

Comment: > But note that this works only with literals - and there is no way to make it works with arbitrary values? In swift3 same situation?

Comment: @ShadowOf: Very early Swift versions had the possibility to define arbitrary conversion methods, but that was removed long ago. As far as I know, the situation is unchanged in Swift 3.