# How to make a structure auto-convertible from a tuple literal?

Tags: swift

In Swift, it is possible to convert certain literals to other types automatically:

```
let _: Double = 1  // Int literal to Double variable
```

However, when it comes to structs, compiler refuses to perform a similar conversion:

```
struct User {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
}

let _: User = (id: 778, name: "Pete")  // error: cannot convert value of type '(id: Int, name: String)' to specified type 'User'
```

Defining an initialiser with respective fields does not help either.

Is there a way to omit the explicit initialiser of a structure, when the type is clear from the context?

Comment: There is a limited set of "literal convertible" protocols, like IntegerLiteralConvertible and FloatLiteralConvertible, and Double adopts both. You can adopt them in your own type (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160889/may-i-create-an-instance-of-a-structure-using-a-simple-int9) but you cannot define your own "literal convertible" protocol.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/expressiblebytupleliteral-instead-of-tuples-conforming-to-protocols/29626 https://forums.swift.org/t/implementing-expressiblebytupleliteral-how-hard/21169 and my favorite: https://forums.swift.org/t/make-tuple-syntax-a-shorthand-for-initializing-a-contextual-type/33740

Answer (score 4):

In Swift, the only literals that can be used to instantiate a type are `Int`, `Double`, `String`, `Bool`, and `Array`'s and `Dictionary`'s. **Tuples are not allowed.**

Swift aims to be a strongly typed langage, so you should use:

`let user = User(id: 778, name: "Pete")`

Which is both explicit and short, and not more verbose than what you are looking for.

---

However, you can conform any of your type to any `ExpressibleBy<LiteralType>Literal`. Here is a fun way to achieve a similar behavior to tuple initialization:

```swift
struct User {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
}

extension Person: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Any)...) {
        let elements = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements)
        self.id = elements["id"]! as! Int
        self.name = elements["name"]! as! String
    }
}

let user: User = ["id": 778, "name": "Pete"]
```

Which is both unsafe and inefficient.

---

A safer but less convenient way is using a static factory method:

```swift
extension User {
    static func t(_ tuple: (Int, String)) -> User {
        User(id: tuple.0, name: tuple.1)
    }
}

let user: User = .t((id: 778, name: "Pete"))
```

---

Another interesting thing is that in certain contexts, the compiler will allow the use of a tuple which exactly matches an initializer signature to be used, for instance when using `map`:

```swift
let persons = [(id: 778, name: "Pete")]
let users = persons.map(User.init)
```

Comment: That's conceptually an `init`, not a `static func`.

Comment: Yes I agree, the `static func` variant saves some characters (`init` → 't'). Bu anyway, it is juste an ugly workaround that does not save the OP question.