# Literal Convertibles in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I want to know how Literal Convertibles work in Swift. The little I know is that the fact that, in `var myInteger = 5`, myInteger magically becomes an `Int` is because `Int` adopts a protocol, `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` and we don't have to do `var myInteger = Int(5)`. Similarly `String`, `Array`, `Dictionary` etc all conform to some Literal protocols.
My Question is

1. Am I right in my little understanding of Literal Convertibles?
2. How can we implement these in our own types. For example

---

```
 class Employee {
    var name: String
    var salary: Int
    // rest of class functionality ...
}
```

---

How can I implement Literal Protocols to do `var employee :Employee = "John Doe"` which will automatically assign "John Doe" to employee's name property.

Comment: Example for  ExpressibleByStringLiteral (duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373776/swift-struct-initialization-making-another-struct-like-string. For ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160889/may-i-create-an-instance-of-a-structure-using-a-simple-int. A possible application: https://oleb.net/blog/2017/01/fun-with-string-interpolation/.

Comment: Please, don't abuse literals for initializing custom classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift struct initialization, making another struct like String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373776/swift-struct-initialization-making-another-struct-like-string)

Comment: I would definitely avoid this. Making a `myInteger` from an integer literal makes sense. Making a `MyCustomSortedDictionary` from a Dictionary literal makes sense. Making an `Employee` from a String literal... does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are partially correct in your understanding of the various `ExpressibleBy...Literal` protocols. When the Swift compiler parses your source code into an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), it already identified what literal represents what data type: `5` is a literal of type `Int`, `["name": "John"]` is a literal of type `Dictionary`, etc. Apple makes the base type conform to these protocols for the sake of completeness.
2. You can adopt these protocols to give your class an opportunity to be initialized from a compile-time constant. But the use case is pretty narrow and I don't see how it applies to your particular situation.

For example, if you want to make your class conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, add an initializer to set all your properties from a `String`:

```
class Employee: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    typealias StringLiteralType = String

    var name: String
    var salary: Int

    required init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        let components = value.components(separatedBy: "|")
        self.name = components[0]
        self.salary = Int(components[1])!
    }
}
```

Then you can init your class like this:

```
let employee1: Employee = "John Smith|50000"
```

But if you dream about about writing something like this, it's not allowed:

```
let str = "Jane Doe|60000"
let employee2: Employee = str // error
```

And if you pass in the wrong data type for `salary`, it will be a run time error instead of a compile-time error:

```
let employee3: Employee = "Michael Davis|x" // you won't know this until you run the app
```

**TL, DR:** it is a very bad idea to abuse these `ExpressibleBy...Literal` types.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a scenario to work with Convertibles in custom types.

```
 struct Employee : ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
        var name: String = ""
        init() {}
        init(stringLiteral name: String) {
            self.name = name
        }
    }

    func reportName(_ employee: Employee) {
        print("Name of employee is \(employee.name)")
    }
    reportName("John Doe") //Name of employee is John Doe
```